# A query regarding re-defining the ```\lim``` command in ```amsart```

Tags: renewcommand

I was trying to redefine the command `\lim`, but I was getting an error messege. The code was analogous to the following:

```
\documentclass[oneside,10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\newcommand{\li}{\lim\limits}
\renewcommand{\lim}{\li}
```

[image]

Any sort of help regarding the issue will be of great help.

Regards,
Ralph

P.S: Is it happening because of the `\lim\limits` in the definition of `\li`? Just a wild guess.

Comment: You're making an infinite loop: the new `\lim` expands to `\li\limits` which expands to `\lim\limits`, which gives `\li\limits\limits` and so on. And you don't want to apply `\limits` indiscriminately, trust me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do, from a terminal, `latexdef -c amsart lim`, you obtain

```
\lim:
macro:->\qopname \relax m{lim}
```

You cannot go the way you do, because TeX expands macros and, with your definitions, you get successively

```
\lim
\li\limits
\lim\limits
\li\limits\limits
\lim\limits\limits
...
```

so you see that an infinite loop is created that soon fills TeX's memory (the input stack, as the error message says).

You *might* do

```
\documentclass[oneside,10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\NewCommandCopy{\originallim}{\lim}
\renewcommand{\lim}{\originallim\limits}
```

If you have an older TeX system (Overleaf is a candidate to not support `\NewCommandCopy` yet), you can replace the line

```
\NewCommandCopy{\originallim}{\lim}
```

with

```
\let\originallim\lim
```

because the initial `latexdef` tells us that this is safe.

However, you don't really want this. Let me show an example

```
\documentclass[oneside,10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewCommandCopy{\originallim}{\lim}
\renewcommand{\lim}{\originallim\limits}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-2]
$\lim_{x\to0}x^2=0$
\lipsum[2][1-3]
$\lim_{x\to0}x^2=0$
\lipsum[3][1-3]
$\lim_{x\to0}x^2=0$
\lipsum[4][1-3]

\end{document}
```

You get the output

[image]

that you should compare to what you'd get without the redefinition

[image]

I have no doubt on which one is better (the latter, of course). But the choice is yours.

Comment: Thanks @egreg! it's really helpful!